# .htaccess working on windows however not working on apache2 in ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I am using the following htaccess code in XAMPP on windows it works fine. However the same code does not work on Ubuntu Apache2,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?cmd=$1&caseSno=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /?cmd=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /?cmd=$1 [NC,L]
```

without .htaccess file i am using my website links like this:

```
http://localhost/index.php?cmd=home
```

which working fine.

but after using .htaccess file as the above code, i have changed my links to:

```
http://localhost/home
```

But in ubuntu these rules are not working.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: Are you getting 404?

Comment: Yes, Not Found
The requested URL /causeList was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled? Also check the AllowOverride directive settings on your Apache conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following: 
[write the following command on your terminal]

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Check your file if there  is any # sign before the 

AccessFilename .htaccess
```

remove # sign.

Go to the following and change **None** to **All**

```
<directory /var/www/> 
   Options Indexes FollowSysLinks
   AllowOeverride None
   Require all granted
</directory>
```

Replace

```
**AllowOverride None** to **AllowOverride All"
```

That's all you done.

Comment: yes of course and also check that you have enabled the mod_rewrite on. and then after you done the above you must have to restart your apache service